# How to convert ARGB to RGB array of bytes?

Tags: java, rgb, argb

I have a byte array:

```
byte[] blue_color = {-1,0,112,-64};
```

How to convert into byte array of RGB?

And also how can I get the real RGB value of the color?

Comment: You should probably learn what is ARGB and what is RGB...

Comment: No, you are asking something completely different.

Comment: sorry, what I mean is having argb color represented as byte array, and covert it to real rgb value.

Comment: What is real rgb value for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to convert ARGB array into RGB?

```
byte[] argb = ...;
byte[] rgb = new byte[(argb.length / 4) * 3];

int index = rgb.length - 1;

for (int i = argb - 1; i >= 0; i -= 4) {
  rgb[index--] = argb[i];
  rgb[index--] = argb[i - 1];
  rgb[index--] = argb[i - 2];
}
```

How to print integer value:

```
byte[] oneColor = {..., ..., ..., ...};

int alpha = oneColor[0] & 0xFF;
int red = oneColor[1] & 0xFF;
int green = oneColor[2] & 0xFF;
int blue = oneColor[3] & 0xFF;

System.out.println("Color: " + alpha + ", " + red + ", " + green ", " + blue);

System.out.println("Hexa color: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(alpha) + " " + Integer.toHexString(red) + " " + Integer.toHexString(green) + " " + Integer.toHexString(blue));
```

Could be done prettier with `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's the first element that's the A component:

```
byte[] rgb = Arrays.copyOfRange(blue_color, 1, 4);
```

To get the "real" colour values, you need to undo the two's complement representation:

```
int x = (int)b & 0xFF;
```

Comment: there is no copyOfRange method (I use java 1.5)

Comment: @kenny Then use `System.arraycopy()`.

Comment: How to use `System.arraycopy` when he wants to skip one element?

Comment: but what is the rgb real value of this color?

Comment: @Sulthan `System.arraycopy(blue_color, 1, rgb, 0, 3);`

Comment: Well, yes. I thought he meant an array of colors, not one color.

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert into byte array of RGB?

```
byte[] rgb = new byte[3];
System.arraycopy(blue_color, 1, rgb, 0, 3);
```

---

> And also how can I get the real RGB value of the color?

```
int red = rgb[0] >= 0 ? rgb[0] : rgb[0] + 256;
int green = rgb[1] >= 0 ? rgb[1] : rgb[1] + 256;
int blue = rgb[2] >= 0 ? rgb[2] : rgb[2] + 256;
```

Comment: They are not. 256 must be added to negative values.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth oops, I meant `+ 256` ;)